# Setting a different architecture than MobileNet

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am following a codelab tutorial by Google for image recognition:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#3

However, in this case the tutorial is using MobileNet v1 for object detection. In fact, these env variables are set:

```
IMAGE_SIZE=224
ARCHITECTURE="mobilenet_0.50_${IMAGE_SIZE}"
```

But what if I would like to use MobileNet with SSD or SquezeNet for object detection? I guess ARCHITECTURE variable must change in something like

```
ARCHITECTURE="ssd_mobilenet_0.50_${IMAGE_SIZE}"
```

I can't find any helpful resource.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are following is using [this retrain script](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/blob/master/scripts/retrain.py) which is an older version of [the official tensorflow retrain script](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py).

While you can only use either MobileNet or InceptionV3 by using the codelab script, you can follow the [official documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/tree/master/examples/image_retraining) on image retraining to retrain using any model available on [Tensorflow Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Olivier Dehaene thank you for your answer. However, there are no ssd mobilenet v1 or SqueezeNet in the repository containing the available models.

Comment: Then you can't use this script without any modifications to use these models and will have to write your own fine tuning script. 
FYI this task is called image classification and not object detection which is way harder.

Comment: True, there are no bounding boxes..just confidence so this is image classification. My fault. Anyway, thanks for your answers, now I understood I must edit the script.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
MobileNet and SqueezeNet are not suitable for object recognition, but only for image classification. Thus, SSDMobileNet is the possible way.